# Prove that the elements $2x$ and $x^2$ have no LCM in the ring of integral polynomials with even coefficient of $x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, prime-factorization

Let $A$ be the subring of $\Bbb Z[x]$ consisting of all polynomials with even coefficient of $x$.  Prove that the elements $2x$ and $x^2$ have no lowest common multiple.

Hints please!

Comment: Going by the definition of LCM in commutative rings, if $M$ is a least common multiple and $N$ is _any_ common multiple, then M must divide $N$.  Thus an LCM must divide the product $2x\cdot x^2=2x^3$.  But $4x^2$ is also a common multiple in $A$.

Comment: I'm sorry but $2x^2$ is not the lowest common multiple and is also an element of the ring?

Comment: @Giorgio, No, because $2x^2$ is not divisible by $2x$ in the ring $A$.

Comment: Right thanks @Doc :)

Comment: @John, is it okay now?

Comment: @ccorn, $x^2$ is in $A$ since the coefficient of $x$ in $x^2$ is zero, and zero is even.

Comment: @Doc Perfect, thanks! And Giorgio, your question helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the definition of LCM in commutative rings, if $M$ is a least common multiple and $N$ is any common multiple, then $M$ must divide $N$. Thus $p(x)=LCM(2x,x^2)$ must divide the product $2x\cdot x^2=2x^3$. But $4x^2$ is also a common multiple of $2x$ and $x^2$ in $A$. So $p(x)$ divides $4x^2$.  As $4x^2$ does not divide $2x^3$ in $A$, $p(x)$ must be a proper divisor of $4x^2$ that still divides $2x^3$.  Thus either $p(x)=x^2$ or $p(x)=2x$.  But as each fails to divide the other, there is no such $p(x)$.

Comment: I was AFK for a while; the hint was more than enough!  Thanks again.

Comment: Good, good.  Glad I could help.